# Regression to fit data with an integral equation

Tags: fitting, interpolation, integral-equations

I have a set data and I know that this data are best fitted by the following equation, assuming that f($\tau$) is a log normal distribution and $M_{eq}$ = 1.5:

$M(t,\tau)= M_{eq} \int (1-e^{-t/\tau}) f(\tau) d\tau $

I was wondering if there is a way to perform a regression, i.e., by finding the best fitting curve for the given set of data (using the equation above), get the best $f(\tau)$ that improve the best fit as a by-product ?

Thanks in advance

PS.: The set of data that I'm talking about is:

```
data={{0.995, 0.142}, {3.003, 0.2}, {5.908, 0.25}, {10.525, 0.36}, {13.617,
0.498}, {24.321, 0.616}, {33.917, 0.599}, {47.843, 0.7}, {64.172, 
0.835}, {91.353, 1.102}, {126.745, 1.083}, {174.118, 
1.225}, {225.059, 1.133}, {292.998, 1.165}, {369.133, 
1.298}, {640.295, 1.365}, {828.169, 1.298}, {1255.39, 
1.373}, {1496.61, 1.409}, {1942.79, 1.538}}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(* Define function *)
Meq = 3/2;
g[t_?NumericQ, μ_?NumericQ, σ_?NumericQ] :=
 Meq NIntegrate[(1 - Exp[-t/τ]) E^(-((-μ + Log[τ])^2/(2 σ^2)))/(Sqrt[2 π] σ τ), {τ, 0, ∞}]

data = {{0.995, 0.142}, {3.003, 0.2}, {5.908, 0.25}, {10.525, 0.36}, {13.617, 0.498},
   {24.321, 0.616}, {33.917, 0.599}, {47.843, 0.7}, {64.172, 0.835}, {91.353, 1.102},
   {126.745, 1.083}, {174.118, 1.225}, {225.059, 1.133}, {292.998, 1.165},
   {369.133, 1.298}, {640.295, 1.365}, {828.169, 1.298}, {1255.39, 1.373},
   {1496.61, 1.409}, {1942.79, 1.538}};

(* Fit *)
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, {g[t, μ, σ], σ > 0}, {{μ, 4}, {σ, 2}}, t];

(* Summaries *)
nlm["ParameterTable"]
```

[image: Parameter table]

```
nlm["EstimatedVariance"]^0.5
(* 0.06762842122700316` *)

(* Show data, predictions, and 95% confidence bands for the mean *)
lower = Transpose[{data[[All, 1]], nlm["MeanPredictionConfidenceIntervals"][[All, 1]]}];
upper = Transpose[{data[[All, 1]], nlm["MeanPredictionConfidenceIntervals"][[All, 2]]}];
Show[ListLogLinearPlot[{lower, upper, data}, Joined -> {True, True, False},
  PlotStyle -> {{Dotted, Gray}, {Dotted, Gray}, Black}],
 LogLinearPlot[g[t, μ, σ] /. nlm["BestFitParameters"], {t, Min[data[[All, 1]]], Max[data[[All, 1]]]}]]
```

[image: Data, fit, and confidence bands]

Comment: Hi, JimB. Thanks for your feedback. I'd like to know if there is a way to get the distribution $f(\tau)$ without especifing it. I know that the best fit is performed when a log gaussian is used, but what I want to know is if there is a way of inferring about the best distribution a posteriori, without especifing it before.

Comment: Without specifying $f(\tau)$?  No.  But you can use the `"AIC"` or `"AICc"` options to rank potential distributions.  You can get the $AIC_c$ value for the above model with `nlm["AICc"]`.

Comment: Thanks, JimB! I'll try this.