# How to fit my data with following equation?

Tags: numerical-integration, fitting, physics

I have set of data of electronic specific heat ($C_{el}/\gamma_n T$) vs  temperature ($T/T_c$). My fit equation is this

$$\frac{C_{el}}{\gamma_n T}=-\frac{6}{\pi ^2}\alpha \frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} t}\int_{0}^{\infty }[f*\ln(f)+(1-f)*\ln(1-f)]dy$$

$t=T/T_c$, $f$ is the fermi distribution given by ;

$f(y)= \frac{1}{\exp\left[\frac{\alpha }{t}\sqrt{(\tanh [1.837(1/t-1)^{0.51}])^2+y ^2}\right]+1}$;

$\alpha$ is the fit parameter, you may consider $T_c=5.5$

I tired the precription given here

[Regression to fit data with an integral equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/204200/regression-to-fit-data-with-an-integral-equation/204215)

My Code is here,

```
 h[α_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ] := {-6*α/(3.14*3.14)}*
 NIntegrate[{D[
 1/(Exp[α*Sqrt[{Tanh[1.837*(1/t - 1)^0.51]}^2 + y^2]/t] + 
      1)*Log[1/(Exp[α*
         Sqrt[{Tanh[1.837*(1/t - 1)^0.51]}^2 + y^2]/t] + 
       1)] + (1 - 
     1/(Exp[α*
          Sqrt[{Tanh[1.837*(1/t - 1)^0.51]}^2 + y^2]/t] + 1))*
   Log[1 - 1/(Exp[α*
          Sqrt[{Tanh[1.837*(1/t - 1)^0.51]}^2 + y^2]/t] + 1)], 
 t]}, {y, 0, ∞}]


 data ={{0.323195763636364, 0.557840860024079}, {0.3319006, 
         0.600799934804363}, {0.340886127272727, 
         0.639986318375706}, {0.350119945454545, 
         0.684545283774048}, {0.359194854545455, 
         0.728787028493261}, {0.368262672727273, 
         0.772480596303758}, {0.387033745454545, 
         0.863418707901043}, {0.404678218181818, 
         0.946863864480626}, {0.422561781818182, 
         1.02894174605389}, {0.440560345454545, 
         1.11675853096735}, {0.458469018181818, 
         1.19588702561508}, {0.476289709090909, 
         1.28900356908129}, {0.494352181818182, 
         1.36753194268344}, {0.512513345454545, 
         1.44442382687088}, {0.530577054545455, 
         1.52513860255128}, {0.5486574, 
         1.61268757899016}, {0.566630236363636, 
         1.69269182859118}, {0.585813963636364, 
         1.78197494463705}, {0.603859690909091, 
         1.86220641802506}, {0.6219008, 1.94677692856268}, {0.6399708, 
         2.00731512950989}, {0.658087109090909, 
         2.08321672050786}, {0.676063945454545, 
         2.12679996044762}, {0.694120345454545, 
         2.1477241658178}, {0.712211690909091, 
         2.13555291300178}, {0.730382418181818, 
         2.08868342579632}, {0.748460254545455, 1.99235135395404},               {0.766518,1.87432757925883}, {0.784746472727273, 
          1.72926503701623}, {0.802872163636364, 
          1.57054700458995}, {0.821021909090909`, 
           1.394635463767}, {0.839189509090909, 
        1.21470123109364}, {0.857382636363636, 
     1.06475296666267}, {0.875464654545455, 
    0.985450924714613}, {0.893474036363636, 
      0.95402882420539}, {0.911454581818182, 
       0.943518363030918}, {0.929713109090909, 
       0.934769247994782}, {0.947911345454545, 
  0.935941815054016}, {0.966096345454545, 
   0.928426646734778}, {0.984215145454545, 
 0.923517882734191}, {1.00237921818182, 0.924673756273926}}
  (*Fit*)
 nlm = NonlinearModelFit[
 data, {h[t, δ], δ > 0}, {{δ, 0.5}}, t];
 (*Summaries*)
 nlm["ParameterTable"]
 Parameter table
 nlm["EstimatedVariance"]^0.5
*Show data, predictions, and 95 % confidence bands for the mean*)
 lower = Transpose[{data[[All, 1]], 
 nlm["MeanPredictionConfidenceIntervals"][[All, 1]]}];
```

This code is not working.
 Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe26

Comment: Please give some information about what you have already tried using the software Mathematica. This will help others to give you some advice and maybe even answer your question. Give a list of data if you need to fit using the equation. Also try to have the code / data formatted so it can be copied directly into Mathematica.

Comment: @NilabjaKantiSarkar it would be better (& make it a lot easier for us to help you!) if you updated your question with that data, along with your Wolfram Language code attempts in Mathematica :)

Comment: @NilabjaKantiSarkar when you write Ces I assume you meant Cel right? the specific heat

Comment: yah. Sorry for the typo

Comment: I don't see a definition for `Tc`.  And is 3.14 supposed to be an approximation for $\pi$?

Comment: Yah, they were. I changed my code so that I can avoid kb and other const which may introduce too small or big numbers which may be beyond calculation limt of Mathematica. I suspect that `NIntegrate` is not working.

Comment: You need to do some step-by-step debugging.  You've got curly brackets where parentheses should be.  In the `NonlinearModelFit` command you've got the position of $t$ and $\delta$ reversed.  In `D[...]` $t$ is used both as a value and as a variable.  First get the integral to work.

Comment: can you point out some where I have to change from curly brackets to parentheses?

Comment: All are in the `NIntegrate` statement.  Start with `{Tanh` but leave `{y,0,Infinity}` as is.